# Loading failed for the <script> with source on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iis, https

Im having huge problem with loading scripts on my site. I`m using IIS10 to host my webapp: https://testapp.[hosting].pl/Demo

On firefox 61.0.1 The `AllTypescripts.js` and `Config.json` are getting:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source
```

On chrome everything works fine. Using only http works fine for both browser. Also if I place the scripts into Content/Scripts/ then they load fine.

Comment: I'm also running after an answer. If you find me, I'll inform you here.

Comment: Check whether you are installed an adblock plugin to the browser. if so, check reloading with plugin temporary deactivated